# How to find precise numbers in line and print the line with them?

Tags: bash

I have a file with table:

```
1.59    29.206  0.203728775894573   4   60
1.6537  355.592 0.212182437055971   4   0
1.59    29.206  0.203728775894573   3   45
```

I am trying to print the line with numbers `4 0`.

I tried to use this code.

```
    t=4
    v=0
    line=$(grep -F "$t" prediction.txt  | grep -F "$v")
    echo -e $line
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
awk '$4 == 4 && $5 == 0' prediction.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
grep -e "4   0$" zz
```

set the proper delimiter, number of spaces between 4 and 0